# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0xa98e050>

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uinavigationcontroller

While compiling the code i got

> "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for `<UINavigationController: 0xa98e050>`"

warning.

Here is my code

```
KVPasscodeViewController *passcodeController = [[KVPasscodeViewController alloc] init];
passcodeController.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:passcodeController];
[(UIViewController *)self.delegate presentModalViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 63):

I know this is an old question, but for the sake of those who run across this again, here is what I've found.

Firstly, The question does not state where the new `viewController` was being called.
I suspect this was called from `-(void)viewDidLoad`

Move the appropriate code to `-(void)viewDidAppear:` and the problem should go away.

This is because at `-viewDidLoad`, the view has loaded, but has not yet been presented and the animations and views have not completed.

If your intent is to push a window, do it after the window has been presented and has painted.

If you ever find yourself using timers to control system behavior, ask yourself what you are doing wrong, or how you could do it more properly.

Comment: This is the right answer for me, and also explains in simple terms what is going on. I had done the same thing and presented a view modally before the animation of the previous view was finished.

Comment: @Mark Travis: In my situation I can't call from 'viewDidAppear'. I am using ContainerViewClass and switching the view controller based on some action. This warning message always comes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632106/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-while-containerview-sw

Comment: This is the proper solution, and is even found to be required in at least one Apple demo, namely MyImagePicker, whereby the error message ViewController results in such a warning.

Comment: I was indeed calling it in the `viewDidLoad` and moving that code in to the `viewDidAppear` resolved it. This is the correct answer.

Comment: Using Xcode 9.1 and swift 4 and storyboardless project (I do everything programmatically ) I got the problem even when I presented a viewController from ViewDidAppear. Solved the issue with inserting the code of the presented controller ViewDidLoad inside async block
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {}.

Answer (score 18):

I Found that this issue occurs if you trying to push new view controller while previous transaction (*animation*) in progress.

Anyway, i think, it is `presentModalViewController` problem, Set `animated:NO`, **may be solve your problem**

```
[(UIViewController *)self.delegate presentModalViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:NO];
```

**Other option is:**

Take `NSTimer` and call above code between may be **0.50 to 1** second. This also helpful trick. so your pervious viewController has done its animation.

Comment: yes I tried to introduce a timer; i just thought it was a hack but if this is the accepted solution....I was worried that I had something fundamentally wrong in my code, i.e., I wasn't doing it the proverbial apple way, hence the error.

Comment: Andreas. If there are "plenty of other, better ways" then why don't you specify them here. As it is your comment is not constructive.

Answer (score 11):

This warning appears when you try to load a new viewController before a previously included one is done animating.  If your intention is to do that, simply add your code to a `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` block:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [(UIViewController *)self.delegate presentModalViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES];
});
```

and the warning will go away.

Answer (score 3):

a modern solution may be this:

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds *   NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:yourVC animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide much context, so I assume this error is happening at startup since you are presenting a passcode view controller.

In order to get rid of this warning, I register the app delegate as a delegate of the navigation root view controller:

```c
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ((UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController).delegate = self;
    return YES;
}
```

Then I present the modal view controller in `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` with a `dispatch_once`:

```c
- (void) navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        KVPasscodeViewController *passcodeController = [[KVPasscodeViewController alloc] init];
        passcodeController.delegate = self;

        UINavigationController *passcodeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:passcodeController];
        [(UIViewController *)self.delegate presentViewController:passcodeNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}
```

Since `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` is called after the root view controller did appear, the *Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions* warning is gone.