# MFMailComposeViewController Opens then closes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios7

I've got a MFMailComposeViewController and I believe it is implemented correctly. However when it is displayed on the screen (through modal) it just opens, hangs for a second, then closes and logs `MFMailComposeResultCancelled`

any thoughts?

```
            if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
                MFMailComposeViewController *composer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];



                if( composer == nil ){
                    UIAlertView* alert_view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"message"
                                                                          message:@"You will need to setup a mail account on your device before you can send mail!"
                                                                         delegate:nil
                                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert_view show];
                    return;
                }else{



                composer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
                [composer setSubject:@"I have an issue"];
                [composer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
                [composer setToRecipients:@[@"email"]];
                }


                [self presentViewController:composer animated:YES completion:^{
                    ;
                }];
```

EDIT found these in the log

`Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0xcda5e90>.`

`The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4097.)`

Comment: Are you trying to present more than 1 view controller at the same time?

Comment: I dont feel like i am, but the `Unbalanced Calls` seems to speak otherwise

Comment: Check this post: [Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: 0xa98e050>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412890/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-uinavigationcontroller)

Comment: Yea took a look at that though setting the animation to nil didnt work. it still calls `MFMailComposeResultCancelled` and dismisses itself

Comment: Where is this code getting called from? What is the object represented by `self`? Perhaps that object is being released.

Comment: @ChrisH So the object that it's being called from is a UITableviewcontroller. and it is being called when `didselectItemAtIndexPath` is run.

Comment: Also i noticed one thing that stood out, the right Navigation button item is disabled. Not sure if that has anything to do with it. But also where i set `setToRecipients:` that actually isnt placed into the recipents field. even if i enter an actual email with '@'

Comment: Did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18978864/cannot-show-modal-viewcontroller-in-ios7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MFMailComposeResultCancelled is called if you have any changes that occur to the UI when the MFMailComposer is pulled up.

I must be the default iOS Navigation header, though you can change the tint.

Answer (score 0):

On your completion if you don't do anything, put `nil`, probably this is the problem.

Comment: still getting the problem, though in the log i am given some more info ill post it above

Comment: Ok, give us the log please :)